# Aggregate words ending with a set of patterns into a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have Excel 2010 and I am trying to consolidate a list of words.

1. **Sheet1** contains a column with a list of words such as 'ing', 'ed', 'en'....
2. **Sheet2** contains a column with words such as 'Flying', 'Opening', 'Taken', 'Baked', 'Awaken' etc.
3. **Sheet3**, for every column value in Sheet1, I want a function that compares the word with all the words from Sheet2 and collects them together in sheet3.

So, **Sheet3** should have 3 columns after running this

- first column should have 'Flying', 'Opening' - all words ending with 'ing'
- second column should have 'Baked' - all words ending with 'ed'
- third column should have 'Taken', "Awaken' - all words ending with 'en'

I tried using the formula below for one of the words and it seems to work for one word at a time but I am not sure how to automate this - do I need to use a macro for this ?

**=IF(RIGHT(A1:A7, 3)="ing", A1:A7, "")**

Can anyone please suggest how to approach this ?

Regards,
Sonu

Comment: Using `IF` statements you can only reference one row at a time for this kind of thing, e.g.
row 1: `=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)="ing",A1,"")`
row 2: `=IF(RIGHT(A2,3)="ing",A2,"")` etc.
But this would leave you with gaps in your sheet3 table.  Filters or automation (or a combination of both) would give you a consolidated results table, but you'd have to clarify a little before I could supply you with code.  Screenshots might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my request for clarification - I have re-read and now understand your question.

The following code will work for what you describe.  It assumes the following:

1. The list of word endings in Sheet1 and the list of words in sheet2
   are both contiguous lists starting from cell A1 and extending
   downwards.
2. Cell A1 in Sheet2 contains a column heading, e.g. "My Words" which will not be copied to the columns of words in Sheet3.  If you want the heading copied, remove `.Offset(1,0)` from line 13.
3. There are no more entries in the list on Sheet1 than there are columns available to you in your version of Excel (e.g. XL2003=256)
4. Sheet3 is empty prior to the macro starting
5. You have not changed the default VBA codenames of the 3 worksheet
   objects
6. The sheets are not protected

.

```
Sub extract()
Dim rFilt As Range
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim iTgtCol As Integer

    If Sheet2.FilterMode Then Sheet2.ShowAllData
    If Not Sheet2.AutoFilterMode Then Sheet2.Cells(1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter

    Set rSrc = Sheet2.Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)

    iTgtCol = 0

    For Each rFilt In Sheet1.Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells

        iTgtCol = iTgtCol + 1

        With rSrc
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & rFilt
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet3.Cells(iTgtCol)
        End With

    Next rFilt

    Sheet2.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi blackworx, thank you for your detailed reply. I have never executed VBA code in Excel and was wondering where to execute this code - I googled and was able to get the Developer tab to show up in the ribbon. Then I clicked on the Visual Basic tab on the top but it shows the three sheets and I didnt know which sheet to execute this code in. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Ah, never mind - I ran the code in Sheet1 and saw the results in Sheet3 - Is there a way to get a column heading saying - 'Words ending with xxx' on each column in Sheet3 ?

Comment: Hi Sonu, yes you can get this.  Change line 13 so that it reads: `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet3.Cells(iTgtCol).Offset(1,0)` and add the following line between lines 13 and 14: `Sheet3.Cells(iTgtCol) = "Words ending with " & rFilt` HTH :)